# Splitting data by week

Tags: c#, .net

I have a data object that has a timestamp:

```
class MyDataObject
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }

    public MyDataObject(DateTime timestamp, int value)
    {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In the main method, I create a lot of these data objects over the timespan of 18 days (2.5 weeks):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyDataObject> data = new List<MyDataObject>();

        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now, 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(6), 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(8), 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(12), 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(14), 1));
        data.Add(new MyDataObject(DateTime.Now.AddDays(18), 1));
    }
```

I need to divide this data by weeks, so that the data between days 1 to 6 need to be placed in an array, data between days 8 to 14 in another, and the one in day 18 goes in another array all by itself.

I need to create a 2D List of some sort and somehow divide the data in an "array of arrays" but I'm stumped. I suspect I need to use List.FindAll but I've never used it before and have no idea how I can use it in this case.

Comment: Weeks starting with which day of the week... Sunday to Saturday, or Monday to Sunday, etc?

Comment: At first - focus on function, that returns week number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you can use LINQ, you'd just want something like:

```
var groupedByWeek = data.GroupBy(item => GetStartOfWeek(item.timestamp));
```

... where `GetStartOfWeek` would return a `DateTime` at the start of the given week, e.g.

```
public static DateTime GetStartOfWeek(DateTime value)
{
    // Get rid of the time part first...
    value = value.Date;
    int daysIntoWeek = (int) value.DayOfWeek;
    return value.AddDays(-daysIntoWeek);
}
```

That will give you a Sunday-based week. You'd need to adjust it a bit to consider a week starting on Saturday, Monday or whatever.

Comment: How would you calculate the sum of `MyDataObject.value` for each week?

Comment: @MikeBarnes: Well once you've got the groups, you can use `.Select(g => g.Sum(x => x.value))` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you want to do is get the week number of the given timestamp. Well, the [`GetWeekOfYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx) method is designed to do just that. And with LINQ's [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) extension method, dividing up the list into different weeks is pretty easy.

```
using System.Globalization; // for Calendar
using System.Linq; // for GroupBy

...

DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar
var groups = data.GroupBy(x => cal.GetWeekOfYear(
    x.timestamp, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek));
```

Comment: Note that this will put the same week of *different years* together. That may be what's required... but it's not clear.

Comment: That's true. You could always group by, `new { year = x.timestamp.GetYear(), week = ... }` or something similar to suit your particular needs.